# since ugrade to 18.04, gstreamer requires a missing library: libiconv

Tags: gstreamer

My installation of gstreamer has been broken  since I upgraded to 18.04:`$ gst-launch-1.0
gst-launch-1.0: error while loading shared libraries: libiconv.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I cannot find this library (I have seen posts saying that it is part of libc6 but libc6 is installed and liniconv is absent).

How could I repair gstreamer?

Added for N0rbert:

```
$ ldd $(which gst-launch-1.0) | egrep "not|local"
libiconv.so.2 => not found
libpcre.so.1 => not found
```

Comment: Please add output of `ldd $(which gst-launch-1.0) | egrep "not|local"` to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. The problem came from a realy bad interaction between `gstreamer` and `anaconda`, the environment for python development that I am using.

I totally removed `anaconda` (https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/) and now `gstreamer` works correctly.

Weird!

I will now simply use `pip` to install python packages...